# Siunitx formatting rendered differently on Overleaf compared to local compilation

Tags: tables, siunitx

I recently noticed that the following LaTeX code renders differently on Overleaf compared to my local compilation:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{S[table-align-text-after = false]}
\toprule
{Some Values} \\
\midrule
-123.123 \textsuperscript{*} \\
12.34 \textsuperscript{***}\\
975,31 \textsuperscript{*}\\
-44.268 \textsuperscript{\emph{a}} \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Locally:
[image]

Overleaf:
[image]

I assume that the local compilation is the "right" one because it respects the option `able-align-text-after = false`. In both cases, the code is compiled using TexLive version 2021 and pdflatex; no errors are produced. What other parameters could I tweak to make Overleaf behave like my local installation?

Interestingly, when I compile locally without this option (i.e., column specification `{S}` the result is different yet:

[image]

Is this a hint that Overleaf might have changed the default `siunitx` options behind the scenes?

Comment: Add `\listfiles` to your input and check the resulting `File list` in the `.log` files for the version of `siunitx`

Comment: Ah, I did not know that command! My local version seems to be marginally more up-to-date, 2021-12-03 v3.0.37 vs. 2021-07-26 v3.0.23 on Overleaf. The Overleaf log also contains a lot of what looks like siunitx specifications (such as `\l__siunitx_table_after_box=\box56`) that I cannot find in my local log file. So perhaps this is it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The difference is the fix to https://github.com/josephwright/siunitx/issues/526 (I've just tracked through Git). It's not a trivial change so putting a copy of the fixed `siunitx.sty` into your Overleaf project is the best plan.

Comment: Thank you so much for tracking this down for me (and the world)! This should be a reminder to myself that LaTeX packages are not as monolothic as they sometimes seem and that the good ones are actively maintained on GitHub :)